# How to get the text of a long <style> element

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

I'm using Vue. It applies styles by adding them as `<style>` elements to `<head>`. I'd like to view the contents of one of these styles.

Unfortunately I can't access the data. It always gets truncated at 10001 characters. Things I have tried:

1. `document.getElementById("the_style_element").innerText` - this returns a string but truncated to 10001 characters.
2. Right click on the element -> "Store as global variable". This creates a global variable called `temp1` but its length is still 10001.
3. Right click -> "Edit as HTML" - only lets me edit the first 10001 characters.

Surely there is a way? I am using Electron. Other browsers are not an option.

Comment: I know that this question seems arbitrary but is your stylessheet local or are you ref a third party url?

Comment: You can try save the page locally and then view it, you have the Save Page WE Chrome extension, that can save it to your computer https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof

Comment: The element is added dynamically so I don't see how that would work.

Comment: Luckily I found the cause of my issues another way...